# Paypal Express Payment Execution

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing in vb.net and as of right now I am not using any API's to receive transaction details I have only been using IPN and PDT variables to get my details however I began to notice that, when using Paypal Sandbox to test, after I go through the process of check out, I do receive all the variables of the details but in my test account, there are no transactions shown.

Do I need to be using the REST API in order to actually approve and execute the payment for the transaction in order to complete a transaction? I had assumed that the entire transaction had been completed successful since I was getting all of the details back but now that I noticed there aren't any transactions showing in my account I'm not so sure whats going on?

Here is the code I have been using to view transaction details

```
Dim authToken As String = "c37yqZU7UdVWesSoipRHFOwB3fFLv1CfOKWz10hqp0ULz6dYKrlCNuxp9d0"
    Dim txToken As String = Request.QueryString("tx")
    txToken = "2F816064M1280054A" '"6AX4295820157674V" '"5PD1935338742763G" ' '"70Y83841KE749971T"  '"74C31896AA9005743""2RY90202U2008611C" '"0F824628H9566062P" '"5ET57654YS955312K" '
    Dim strRequest As String = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx=" & txToken & "&at=" & authToken




    'Dim Payerinfo As New PayerInfo
    'Dim trans As New Transaction
    'Dim tra As New PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.Model.GetTransactionDetailsReq




    'post back to either sandbox or live
    Dim strSandbox As String = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
    Dim strLive As String = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strSandbox), HttpWebRequest)
    'req.Headers = valHeader
    'Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

    'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    Dim streamOut As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
    streamOut.Write(strRequest)
    streamOut.Close()
    Dim streamIn As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
    streamIn.Close()

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strResponse) Then

        Dim results As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim reader As New StringReader(strResponse)
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line = "SUCCESS" Then
            'FormView1.Visible = False
            While True
                Dim aLine As String
                aLine = reader.ReadLine
                If aLine IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim strArr() As String
                    strArr = aLine.Split("=")
                    results.Add(strArr(0), strArr(1))
                Else
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'when code below is uncommented remove these two end if's below


            Response.Write("<li> " + results("payer_id") + "</li>")
            Response.Write("<li> " + results("txn_id") + "</li>")
            ' Displays all the keys for results, helps to see what the keys are named for writing to text file
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In results
                Dim v1 As String = kvp.Key
                Dim v2 As String = kvp.Value
                Response.Write(v1.ToString _
                        + ":  " + v2 + "<br /> ")
            Next

        End If
```

Comment: Well, Express Checkout at a _bare minimum_ needs [2 calls to complete a transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/#use-cases). Classic and REST APIs are different implementations.

Comment: Ok so would I make these calls on the return url page that the user is redirected to after checkout is complete on paypal's side?  Is there any simple sample code you could point me to that displays how to implement these calls in vb.net?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. You show how you are verifying IPN or PDT details. Then you ask if you are completing transactions but we don't see what steps you are taking and cannot answer whether anything is missing. However, if you are getting an IPN (or PDT) then that means that _some_ transaction has been made (a payment, order, auth, subscription signup, etc) so you should definitely see that transaction in the receiving account.

Comment: The link explains everything in detail, and is really your best bet. No need to rehash things here. Scroll down a bit and you'll see [sample code for .Net for each call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/#express-checkout-sample-code).

Comment: Or you could go the [NVP way](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#ec) so  it's more "bare metal" - re: you send keys/values to an endpoint. You pretty much control and have full insight to "everything". Hth.

Comment: @EdSF Sorry, You are right they have sample code on there, I did not see it.  I apologize for not being clear, but I am unsure myself whether or not the payment process is being fully completed, I do see now where in my paypal Sandbox account it was showing the transactions, I was accidentally getting signed in to normal paypal and not sandbox.

Comment: The Payment Status variable is set to complete when I display the IPN and PDT details but are their more steps needed to complete a payment here or is it truly complete at this point.